# How to use relative path in Neo4j URI

Tags: neo4j, uri, cypher

I would like to use relative path in my cypher script.

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:../relative/path/to/file.csv" AS row
```

Is it possible?

I checked the [documentation](http://neo4j.com/developer/guide-import-csv/) and I didn't see it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can.

I have a directory structure like thus...

```
- neo4j/
    - data/data_sets/sample.csv
    - neo4j-community-2.2.0/neo4j/bin
```

And a statement like this will return data from the csv file when executed in the browser.

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS 
FROM "file:../data/data_sets/sample.csv" AS row
return row.column1
```